# how to encrypt and decrypt a message by using RSA with signature in android

Tags: android, certificate, rsa, encryption

no key distribution, public and private keys will be known by users (random key generator will not be used). I have to encrypt hashed message with private key in order to provide signature
message will only 10-20 characters, so system can be as simple as it is possible

Comment: I know it's been 5 years, but I have no idea what the question is.  :(

Answer (score 2):

Okay, back up and tell us what you want.  Are you trying to get *privacy* by protecting the contents of the message, or guarantee *authenticity* by showing that the message really came from the originator?

If you're looking for privacy, RSA isn't the way to go: use RSA to generate a private/public pair, and then use them to excahnge keys -- or exchange keys out of band.  Use a streaming algorithm like AES to encrypt the message.

If you just want signature to show the message was originated by who you think it was, then have a look at the [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) on digital signature -- it's reasonably straightforward.

Comment: "streaming algorithm like AES" I think that formulation is a bit misleading since AES is a block-cypher and not a stream-cypher.

Comment: He said signature in the question.

Comment: he also said "encrypt hashed message with private key".

Comment: Well, that is what a signature is.

Comment: No it isn't.  The message remains in clear text.  If it were encrypting the message, the message would be, you know, encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

For generating a digital signature, you don't need to encrypt the hash. Signing is a separate crypto primitive; the hash is not encrypted raw anyway, there's some padding. That said, the code is:

```
Signature Signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
Signer.initSign(MyKey, new SecureRandom()); //Where do you get the key?
byte []Message = MyMessage(); //Initialize somehow
Signer.update(Message, 0, Message.length);
byte [] Signature = Sign.sign();
```

Comment: Thanks for answers
In my project, I have to use RSA, according to my security protocol which is approved by my supervisor, I should do this:
A->B    E(PUBb, [M, E(PRIa, H(M)])
1. B must be sure that message came from A (by signiture: H(M) is encryoted by PRIa so only A could be encrypt it)
2. Only B must be able to read this message; whole message encrypted by PUBb, so only B could decrypt it by his private key

Comment: can you help me now to how to do this in java(for android)?